# How to show 1 result per page in PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I have three restaurants in my database(MySQL)  just for testing and i tried to create some pagination code that would show me one restaurant per page.

So i have implemented some code but my problem is that every page displays me all the restaurants again and again.

```
          <?php
            $page = 1;
            if(isset($_GET['page']))
            {
                $page = $_GET['page'];
            }

                $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM restaurants LIMIT 10". ($page * 10 - 10));
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM restaurants");
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $numberOfPages = $row['c'] / 1;
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfPages; $i++)
                {
                 echo '<a style="margin-left:10px;" href="allrestaurants.php?page='. $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
                }
                if (!empty($query)) 
                {
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
                     {
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
                        {
                            $resId=isset($row['id'])?$row['id']:''; ?>


                    <div class="col-md-4 p-t-30">
                    <!-- Block1 -->
                    <div class="blo1">
                        <?php
                        $q="SELECT * FROM restaurant_images JOIN restaurants ON restaurant_images.resaurant_id=restaurants.id AND restaurants.id='$resId'";
                        $queryRestaunt_image=mysqli_query($con,$q);
                        if (!empty($queryRestaunt_image)) 
                          {
                           if(mysqli_num_rows($queryRestaunt_image)>0)
                         {
                           $count=0;
                            while ($image=mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRestaunt_image)) 
                        {

                            $count++;
                         ?>

                             <a href="restaurantdetails.php?id=<?=$resId?>">
                             <div class="wrap-pic-blo1 bo-rad-10 hov-img-zoom" >
                             <div style="background:url('./images/restaurants/<?=isset($image['image'])?$image['image']:'intro-01.jpg'?>') no-repeat center; background-size:  contain;height:230px; background-color: black">  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                        <?php
                        if($count==1)break;
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

I expect that that i have only one result per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your SQL query to properly use `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants LIMIT <page offset>, <number of restaurants per page>;
```

Example:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM restaurants LIMIT " . ($page - 1) . ", 1");
```

Comment: So if i want to make it 10 results per page  i would do something like                     $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM restaurants LIMIT " . ($page - 10) . ", 10");  ??

Comment: Then change the `1` to `10` in the example, but better define a constant like `ITEMS_PER_PAGE` and use in the query.

Answer (score 0):

`$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM restaurants LIMIT 10". ($page * 10 - 10));`

You can limit to ONE, changing here:

`$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM restaurants LIMIT 1". ($page * 10 - 10));`

Then you would have to check your logic about the pagination system... if 10 in `($page * 10 - 10)` the 10 is used because the default pagination would be 10 results, then you would have to change the 10 for 1 in every line...